# creating snippets of Latex code

Tags: code-snippets

please refer the web page
https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/circuitikz/

[image]

I would like to create my own library of useful snippets from around the www
and there output compilation

How to make a headstart in this direction

--Code can be copied 
--Output can be seen 
--The library will be online

Comment: Like http://www.texample.net/ ? Or https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples?

Comment: how is the snippet stored in the figure above and how is the output stored--what is the software used

Comment: This a **LaTeX** snippet, using the package `circuitikz`. Please look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX , https://www.latex-project.org/about/, or even at https://www.overleaf.com/

Comment: the above figure has a pleasing presentation--black background for the code --the output in its own box --comments are separated out--how to make a start in this direction

Comment: But that is a Web/HTML question --- not a LaTeX one. No idea which system or framework they are using. In the main site there is a notice like that: "design and content © 2019 Claudio Vellage" --- maybe ask them?

Comment: i would like to store it as a pdf file in my google drive for reference--how do I store the code and its corresponding output as shown above in the figure--black background for the code --the output in its own box --comments are separated out--how to make a start in this direction